# How to generate development MDM/APNS certificate?

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, sandbox, apple-push-notifications, mdm

We have taken iOS developer Enterprise account and we have received the MDM certificate which is in .pem format.We have download this mdm certificate from the portal https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/
But we don't have idea that this is production MDM certificate or development MDM certificate.

First we want to test MDM commands using development certificate and after getting MDM payloads,we can can continue for production.

So my question is how to create MDM/APNS certificate which can be used for getting MDM push notification from gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com , if this is possible.

I have gone through [this](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf) pdf,but not getting fair idea about development MDM push notification.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is try production APNS you can use this production APNS for live MDM product also.

If you are following [this](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning) page, then take care of few things and see the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571190/apns-notifications-not-reaching-devices-enrolled-in-apple-mdm/10629174#10629174) also.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this page: http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning

In order to use the sandbox APNS service, tick 'Use Development APNS Server' in the Mobile Device Management section in the iPhone Config Util of the configuration profile you will create to enrol your device with your server.