# How to build mdm solution in development environment.

Tags: ios, mdm

In production environment we can connect with APNS but in development environment some ports remain block due to which we can not  connect to APNS, so does it mean that mdm solution does not work in development environment. Please share if any document is there.

Answer (score 0):

There are no documents. For iOS to work, the server MUST send an APN message to the device once it has surrendered the token to your checkin endpoint.

This means that (development or prod) you should be able to access outbound 2195/2196 (the latter only if you have implemented feedback) for APNS over TCP.

However, since this is a standard TCP, a SOCKS proxy or traffic forwarding by a firewall appliance might work.

Alternatively, you should look into HTTPS/2 APNs, this would be essentially over 443 which might be easier for your network team to unblock.

Answer (score 0):

The production APNS usually works in the development environment too. 
You just need to enable 'Use Development APNS Server' in the Mobile Device Management section in the iPhone Config Util of the configuration profile you will create to enroll your device with your server.

Refer following links:
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10670518/8472539) 
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10427976/8472539)

Comment: Thank you BinOli  for your valuable knowledge sharing. I will try this now